# Login with only facebook Lite not working sometime using latest sdk 4.20.0

Tags: android, facebook-login

I have integrated facebook SDK 4.20.0, its was working from last few days back login with facebook lite. other all login process are working

[image: Only facebook lite is not working sometimes and shows this page]

Comment: sample project https://github.com/jaswinderwadali/fb